# Ввод переменных в python

Tags: python, строки

Смотрите, мне нужно написать код, который решает уравнения вида
`(x ** 2 + a) ** (x * a) / (x - 1)`, решение этого уравнения можно сделать через def

```
def func(a,x)
    return (x ** 2 + a) ** (x * a) / (x - 1)
```

Но как сделать такое решение с помощью `x = input()`, чтобы программа была универсальна для всех уравнений такого типа?

Comment: Под определением функции пишем `func(a, int(input())`? Вообще что нужно сделать — ввести `x`, потом с ним вызвать данную функцию и получить результат или что?

Comment: да, я хочу, чтобы можно было определять эту функцию свободно через ```input()```

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте `sympy` (`pip install sympy`). И ...

```
import sympy

# читает формулу и преобразует её в символический вид
expr = sympy.sympify(input('formula: '))

# перебирает все переменные которые встретились в формуле
for s in expr.free_symbols:

    # подставляет значение на место переменной 
    expr = expr.subs(s, sympy.sympify(input(f'{s}: ')))

print('=', expr)
```

> ```
> $ python sym-calc.py
> formula: 2 * x
> x: 5
> = 10
>
> $ python sym-calc.py
> formula: x ** 2
> x: y ** 2
> = y**4
> ```

**P.S.** Осторожней, системы компьютерной алгебры затягивают: сперва вы играете с вычислителями, затем учитесь их настраивать, затем дополняете алгоритмы, а там уже аспирантура и конец нормальной жизни.

Comment: АХхавхахывхаывх, да не, надеюсь, ну нет, думаю такого не случится

Comment: А как можно сделать, чтобы мне надо было не вводить x и а с клавиатуры, а можно было бы брать их из массива?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Для этого надо сформулировать и правильно задать новый вопрос. Вы кое-что узнали, теперь лучше представляете что вам нужно. Поделитесь?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, нужно ввести любое число (вещественное, скорее всего), а затем вызвать функцию с ним, верно?

Это можно сделать так:

1. преобразуем полученный ввод с помощью `float()`
2. затем подставляем получившееся число в функцию. И да, у нас может
   быть деление на нуль, поэтому учитываем данный случай при помощи
   [исключений](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html)

```py
def func(a,x):
    return (x ** 2 + a) ** (x * a) / (x - 1)

x = float(input('Введите x: '))
a = float(input('Введите a: '))
try:
  y = func(a, x)
  print(y)
except ZeroDivisionError:
  print('Нельзя делить на нуль!')
```

Comment: Ввести любую функцию, но если я напишу ```x = input()``` и в этот x засуну ```(x ** 2 + a) ** (x * a) / (x - 1)```, то этот x будет равен строке, содержащей формулу ```(x ** 2 + a) ** (x * a) / (x - 1)```, а не самой этой формуле

Comment: @trapluv что-то непонятное в комментарии написано...

Comment: @Эникейщик автор хочет, кажется, ввести сам текст формулы, чтобы потом можно было с ней работать через ввод необходимых переменных, но из оригинального текста вопроса это вообще не было понятно =/

Comment: Вот, да, извините за некорректно-написанный текст